# Erro em Enum com JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Ao realizar uma consulta no banco de dados com `JPA` + `HIBERNATE` é lançado a seguinte excessão:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [Respondido] for enum class [java.lang.Enum]
```

Não consigo entender o motivo do erro, na teoria ele deveria estar fazendo o binding corretamente para a coluna do banco de dados.

Este é o meu `Enum` na `@Entity`

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "situacao", nullable = true)
private Enum<SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum> situacao;
```

E esta é a minha query de consulta, estou usando a interface `SimpleJPARepository`.

```
@Query("SELECT situacao FROM AvaliacaoPedido ap WHERE ap.idPedido = :idPedido")
public String consultarSituacaoPedido(@Param("idPedido") Integer idPedido);
```

E este é o meu `Enum`:

```
public enum SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum {

    EsperandoResposta, 
    Respondido, 
    FalhaEnvio, 
    Ignorado, 
    ExcedeuTentativa;
}
```

Já vi em uma pergunta do GUJ que o problema poderia ser que no banco o `Enum` pudesse estar em inteiro, mas este não é o meu caso, os enum no meu banco são todos `String` como vocês podem ver a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @AnthonyAccioly eu realizei o `SELECT DISTINCT` no BD e não havia nenhum valor furado, então fiz o que você disse alterei o `private Enum<SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum> situacao;` para `private SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum situacao;` e funcionou, você poderia me fazer apenas mais 2 favores? 1° - você poderia colocar esse seu comentário como uma resposta para que eu possa marcar a pergunta com o respondido? o 2° é se você não teria algum artigo que você recomenda e que fale sobre essas _type erasure_ gostaria de saber mais sobre o tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está no fato de você estar usando a superclasse comum [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html):

```
private Enum<SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum> situacao;
```

Em oposição ao tipo direto da enum `SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum`:

```
private SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum situacao;
```

Lendo as partes relevantes da [JSR 338 (JPA 2.2)](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdfTX8Ne9ksbTlBLCM_EFQ) e da [Documentação do Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums) todos os exemplos esperam que a anotação `@Enumerated` seja usada diretamente com o tipo da enum.

---

#### E por que o JPA não aceita campos do tipo `Enum<E>`?

Desconheço o motivo. Especulo que esse é um caso de uso mais exótico que eles simplesmente não implementaram.

`Enum` é uma classe base comum a todos os tipos de enumeração. Apesar do uso de `Enum` como campo de uma classe ser incomum, o código abaixo é perfeitamente válido:

```
private Enum<SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum> situacao = SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum.EsperandoResposta;
```

Minha suspeita inicial foi que devido a [*Type Erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) o tipo genérico não estaria acessível em tempo de execução, porém, isso não é verdade. Com auxílio de *reflection* consegui obter o tipo `E` em uma `Enum<E>` e inicializar o campo normalmente através de uma String.

[**Veja funcionando no Ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Zz9ThC)

É claro que há casos mais complicados (e.g., [*Wildcards*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) em cenários como  `private Enum<? extends SituacaoAvaliacaoPedidoEnum> situacao;`, tipos genéricos vindos da classe, etc). É possível que em alguns dos casos mais complicados realmente não seja possível obter o tipo da `Enum`; o mais provável porém é que isso simplesmente não foi implementado.

Com o Hibernate é sempre possível implementar um [Tipo Básico Customizado](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type) para contornar a limitação; dito isso, acredito que na maioria dos casos usar o tipo direto da enum é uma solução mais limpa.